# Send files over static IP from clients to server

Tags: c#, wpf, ip, file-transfer, static-ip-address

I'm a newb in this thing. I want to send files from a few client systems to a server over static IP. They're connected via a LAN. The files are created on a WPF app on clients and should be sent to the server which also has a WPF app.

Comment: the fact that it's a static IP should be meaningless.  You could use a custom WCF service, FTP, or even a simple copy over UNC path since they're on the same LAN

Comment: This isn't a question.  Are you asking about protocols?  What have you considered?

Comment: @bmm6o Yes, I need information about protocols. I've considered WCF. I want it to be simple coz I've never done stuff like this before.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest protocols to you will be the ones you don't have to implement yourself.  Can you use shared network drives, ftp or http?  WCF would also be easy to implement, even if it's overkill.

Comment: I dunno buddy. All the computers are connected via a LAN, so what's the best thing to send files and streams of data?

Comment: There's not enough information to give a real answer.  If you can share a directory on the server, that would be simple.  Can you do it, I don't know.